# How to refer to outer "this" object from an inner class after de-serialization in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I have an object that is serialized with an inner class. After de-serialization the inner class calls a method on the outer class which refers to "this", and it is causing me problems. My code:

```
// Outer Class
public AuctionItem getInstance(){
    return this;
}

private class ItemCallBack extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            AuctionServerIntf aServer = (AuctionServerIntf) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+AuctionServer.HOST+":"+AuctionServer.PORT+"/AuctionServer");
            aServer.notifyItemEnded(getInstance()); // <--- Exception is thrown here
        } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException | NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I want to pass a reference to the outer class to the aServer.notifyItemEnded() method, it works fine before serialization, but afterwards throws a connection exception. Any idea how to solve this? Cheers.

Comment: Throws what exception? stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prepending the class name of the outer class:

```
aServer.notifyItemEnded(AuctionItem.this.getInstance());
```

Comment: I've actually just realised that the problem was with another part of my code, d'oh! In the notifyItemEnded() method I was trying to notify a client who wasn't connected and so it was throwing the Exception I thought was coming from my original question. Your answer worked though, so I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Pretty roundabout way to get `AuctionItem.this`.

Comment: @EJP agreed, but the outer class usage in the question is quite trivial that it looks contrived, so I decided to give a generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Java syntax provided for the job:

```
aServer.notifyItemEnded(AuctionItem.this);
```